# Required attribute not working in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have created this C# file to be scaffolded in ASP.NET 5.0. The problem is I do not want the home number to be required yet the generated page (controller with Entity Framework) **Create** still counts it as such. Any idea why id this happening?

```
public class Patient
    {
        [Key]
        public string MRN { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
        public int MobNumber { get; set; }       
        [Display(Name = "Home Number")]
        public int HomeNumber { get; set; }      
        [Required]
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
            

    }
```

Here is the code for `Create.cshtml`, the weird thing that it used to work, now every time I try to generate the controller along with the views, the Home Number is required.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Patient</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MRN" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MRN" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MRN" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MiddleName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MiddleName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MiddleName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Address" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Gender" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Gender" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MobNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MobNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MobNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="HomeNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="HomeNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="HomeNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Nationality" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Nationality" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Nationality" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: Can you put the controller code for `Create`?

Comment: As noted below, you need to make your property nullable. However, keep in mind that telephone numbers are **not integers**. Using `int` (or `int?`) is a bad choice. Use a string to store these values and use attributes/data annotations to ensure they are valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want values to be required, you should make them nullable:

```
[Display(Name = "Home Number")]
public int? HomeNumber { get; set; }
```